# Can I put high voltage thyristors in series & ZVS to handle MHz frequency resonance?

Tags: resonance, thyristor, zvs

I'm trying to scale up a circuit that calls for a MOSFET and a ZVS to be capable of dealing with high frequencies (1-20 MHz.)

I'm aiming to crank it up to 10 kV and would prefer the systems in series to be able to manage around 20 kV, but that requires thyristors (I'm thinking around 20 in series, 1.2 kV each.)

Will this work the way I'm thinking? Will it be able to manage the high voltage? Will a ZVS be required to keep the thyristor safe or is there some kind of driver unit that's intended for this purpose?

[image: Example 1]

What would this look like to rig up? These are two of the examples I'm working from:

https://www.digikey.ca/en/product-highlight/l/littelfuse/high-voltage-scr-switching-thyristors-sk2xxxd-sk6xxxd-series

This is the kind of thyristor I was thinking of using to substitute the MOSFET.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: *scale up a circuit* Show us that circuit! *Will this work the way I'm thinking?* Show what you're thinking in a schematic drawing, there's a tool for that when you **Edit** your question.

Comment: Schematics are a must for this question. Data sheet links for the devices are also a must have.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie ; sorry first post is that better?

Comment: 1) it is MOSFET and not mosphet 2) Both circuits are unlike anything I have ever seen before and believe me, I have seen lots and lots of circuits over more than 25 years. 3) These circuits look to me like they will **blow up your MOSFET** but feel free to show me how that doesn't happen 4) Explain how the circuit is supposed to work and what it is supposed to do 5) Talking about "crank it up to 10 kV" and using Thyristors is only useful **after** all previous points are adressed.

Comment: What it's suppose to do, at even low voltages is produce electrical discharges at such a frequency that they ignite the air at the discharge point. Effectively a Mosfet driven high frequency tesla coil/slayer exciter. The working principal as I understand it is that the Zero Voltage Switching is the key to not blowing it up(which yes in calibration is a high likelihood), basically the circuit needs to be tuned to switch at the exact moment when current & voltage are doing their "change over" during the sine wave. (To my understanding a Thyristor is a high voltage/vacuum transistor/Mosfet)

Comment: *To my understanding a Thyristor is a high voltage/vacuum transistor/Mosfet* Uhm, no, and that's really really a big **NO**. You should study how these devices behave and not make such rogue assumptions.

Comment: Or you know......ask a community of experts/enthusiasts who can point out the issues with a circuit because of a misconception in the function of a chip. Not sure why you're being hostile; I figured fixing ignorance was the purpose of a question website. I apologize if my ignorance is painful to your sensibilities as a field expert. It was not my intention for this question to irritate anyone. I'm just trying to have some fun studying this phenomenon at higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so firstly, I have never seen a thyristor do anything meaningful at even 1MHz, never mind at 20kV and MHz rates, they just are not that fast.

What you have drawn looks like a fairly crude mosfet based self oscillating power oscillator with some kind of matching network at the output, sort of thing the tesla coil crowd play with.
I would take some convincing that it is zero crossing, but I suppose it may oscillate if you set the bias trimmer correctly, but I would be surprised if it got up into the medium wave band, never mind 20MHz.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AQmaAEyTic  Something like this but with the Mosfet switched out for a thyristor to handle the high voltage & ZVS to allow the mosfet(thyristor) to bypass its frequency limitations. (I've already prepared containment before I started the final circuit)

Comment: @Recramorcen Let me give you a tip: either you build / copy exactly the device that's show in that video. If you're lucky and got all the details right, it might work as is shown in the video. If you make changes, like replacing components with something else completely (MOSFET => Thyristor) then chances are it will not work. We EEs here already **KNOW** it will not work because a Thyristor behaves in a **very** different way than a MOSFET. ...

Comment: ...A Thyrsistor is an on/off swithing device. A MOSFET can also do something in between (have some resistance) which is needed in an oscillator type circuit. A Thyristor simply cannot do that and will not work **period**. But feel free to try that and see for yourself.

Comment: That's fine, a thyristor is just what comes up when searching for high voltage switches; if I am wrong in my selection, then what would you suggest as an appropriate substitute in the circuit. As the Mosfet is the only component that's hard to modify(when scaling voltage) for this application in general. Whatever component is capable of substituting the function of the mosfet in regulating the resonance of the primary & secondary at MHz Frequency.

Comment: @dan mills https://www.mouser.ca/new/ixys/ixys-4500vmosfet-mosfet/ would this work better for my application if placed in series? & would I need a driver(is there one capable )?

Comment: Expensive part that, and has a massive amount of gate capacitance. I would rethink what the hell you are trying to do, I mean at a defined frequency, generate the required amount of power with a low voltage design (say 60V or so with some modern ldmos or such) and just step up as required. It is RF so matching networks are a mundane bit of business. TBH given your clear lack of understanding of how to do high frequency power electronics I would learn some RF engineering first and then look and see if your approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve is sane.

Comment: Given there's literally hundreds of variations of this circuit, & have been for more 100 years , & all I asked was for a suitable substitute when going up in voltage ; the correct logical conclusion is that you're the one mistaken & presenting the fallacious argument. I've presented video evidence, you've presented insults, very poor measure of a man & highly unprofessional. Soviet Circuits shouldn't be a complete mystery a "field expert"

Comment: Its not a mystery, and at below maybe a few hundred kHz will probably be just fine, with the specified supply voltage up it. However you are trying to operate the thing in a different operating regime (Higher frequency actually being the important bit) and that changes design considerations radically, in particular device parasitics now matter. The easy approach is a generator designed to drive a low impedance (below 100R) and a matching network. Someone trying to substitute a thyristor for a mosfet in an oscillator is a reasonable indication that they don't understand what they are about.